# Database operations or http calls using kafka consumer

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache-kafka

I am new to Apache Kafka. I have a few questions?
if you produce topic using Kafka producer and the Kafka consumer received the message

```
consumer.on('message', function (message) {
})
```

so for example, if I want to send data to some DB or to call in API to update my DB, Is it better to do all the codding inside consumer.on method

```
 consumer.on('message', function (message) {
    let data = await getPayload();//get payload
    //console.log(data,'data')
    //pause(topic,0); //pause until the prev request is completed
    request({
        url: process.env.API + '/some-api',
        method: 'POST',
        json: true,
        body: data
      }, function(err, response, body) {
        if (err) {
          console.error('got error', err);
          //resume(topic,0); resume when err/response recived 
        } else {
          // console.log('response', response);
          console.log('body', body);
          //resume(topic,0);
        }
    });
  })
```

Is there any alternative or recomended methods?

Answer (score 1):

While consuming from kafka and loading it to any sink like DB in your case , you need to be aware  handling any failures, exactly one semantics etc.
There is already a database sink connector available (link below), you can check if it suffice you requirements

[kafka-connect-jdbc](https://www.confluent.io/connector/kafka-connect-jdbc/)

Comment: what about API call?